# will C++ thread join return immediately or not?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, join

[std::thread::join](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/join) document says that **"It blocks the current thread until the thread identified by *this finishes its execution."**

But I am confused that when I create several threads and join them one by one, it seems that the previous '**helper1.join'** not blocked next one '**helper2.join**' statement because according to the output result sometimes t1 finish first, sometimes t2 finish first. How can I understand this situations?

example code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>

using namespace std;
void foo()
{
// simulate expensive operation
   std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
   cout<<"this foo"<<endl;
}

void bar()
{
// simulate expensive operation
   std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
   cout<<"this one"<<endl;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << "starting first helper...\n";
    std::thread helper1(foo);

    std::cout << "starting second helper...\n";
    std::thread helper2(bar);

    std::cout << "waiting for helpers to finish..." << std::endl;
    helper1.join();
    helper2.join();

    std::cout << "done!\n";

}
```

Comment: "Block until X finishes" doesn't mean that Y can't finish while you are blocked.

Comment: Just because you let people in in a specific order doesn't mean that they arrived in that same order.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your code you have three threads: the two you start and the one started by the OS, the main thread. The `join` only affects the main thread where it is executed, the `foo` and `bar` threads are started immediately when created. Which one prints its output first depends on the scheduler and is - as you noticed - undetermined. The `join` calls only ensure that the "done!" is printed after the created threads finish.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The "Main" thread waits until all initiated threads join. This fact only guaranties return from threads. The return sequence is promised neither by the order of firing the threads, nor by the complexity or size of each of the functions associated with every single thread.

Of course you can interference in the thread handling process using "Critical Section", "Semaphore" like,etc. concepts.